# How do I get play to look in the conf folder as well a special conf file location?

Tags: playframework, configuration

It seems that when I use the argument:

```
-Dconfig.file=/path/to/file/file.conf
```

the `conf` folder gets removed from the 'conf classpath' and so play complains that it can't find a certain conf file which sits right there in the `conf` folder. Assuming that is the issue here, how could I have play look in both the `conf` folder and the given file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, using Play 2.6, I do not seem to have this issue. According to [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#Specifying-an-alternative-configuration-file) `config.file` should just specify a replacement for `conf/application.conf` and not affect the entire resources classpath:

> These system properties specify a replacement for `application.conf`,
>   not an addition. If you still want to use some values from the
>   `application.conf` file then you can include the `application.conf` in
>   your other `.conf` file by writing include `"application"` at the top of
>   that file.

After specifying `config.file` we can confirm access to `conf/` resources using [`Environment.resource`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/fb5b3e51392fbed1a1e6905f6055bf66fc0d4a2f/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Environment.scala#L70) like so:

```
class ResourceImporter @Inject()(environment: Environment) {
  ...
  environment.resource("some-file-in-conf.data")
  ...
}
```

Executing `sbt "show unmanagedResources"` to list all resources gives

```
play-scala-starter-example git:(2.6.x) ✗ sbt -Dconfig.file=/etc/some.file
...
[play-scala-starter-example] $ show unmanagedResources
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf/logback.xml
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf/application.conf
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf/routes
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 30-Sep-2018 12:50:59
[play-scala-starter-example] $
```

where we see that `conf/` is still on the classpath even after specifying `config.file`

We can [add additional resource directories](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+resource+directory) to the classpath alongside `conf/` using `unmanagedResourceDirectories` like so

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "extra-resources"
```

which now gives

```
[play-scala-starter-example] $ show unmanagedResources
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf/logback.xml
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf/application.conf
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/conf/routes
[info] * /Users/mgalic/sandbox/play-scala-starter-example/extra-resources
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mario! I did want to use some values from the ```application.conf```, so including it does the trick. I refer to a conf file inside ```application.conf``` which lies in the conf directory but it is unable to find: ```Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Key store file conf/certs/local.cert does not exist!```. So if ```conf``` dir is still on the classpath, any clues to what I might be missing here?

Comment: Have you tried omitting `conf/` from the path, that is, specify `certs/local.cert` instead of `conf/certs/local.cert`?

Comment: Turns out the problem here was as simple as providing a fully qualified path to the cert file instead of a relative one.